# How do I assign a div to a table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add some padding to the bottom of a table. The table is meant to be blue in color. When I add the padding, it retains the colour of the table, while i would like it to be white in colour.

The table is not part of any div yet. If I could assign the table to a div, I may be able to add a new white table to the div which can serve as a padding. How could I assign a table to a div in jquery?

Edit:

This is the code that I used. The table is meant to be blue and at the bottom of the window no matter what the screen size is of the monitor. 
If there is no scrollbar, the table is placed at a distance from the bottom of the screen.
 If however there is a scrollbar, the table is placed right at the bottom. To overcome this, I need to add padding to the bottom of the table. However the padding also turns to be blue.

```
function setTable(){
    var _width = $('.table2').innerWidth();
    var _top = $(document).height();
    _top -= 150;


    $(":input").each(function (index){
        var _id = $(this).attr("id");
        var _trDisplayStyle = "";

        switch(_id){
        case "A":
        case "B":
        case "C":

        if($(this).parents("tr").attr("style")){
            _trDisplayStyle = $(this).parents("tr").css('display');
        }
        if(_trDisplayStyle !== "none"){
            $(this).parents("table").attr("bgcolor","blue");
            $(this).parents("table").attr("height","30px");
            $(this).parents("table").attr("width",_width);
            $(this).parents("table").css({top:_top,position:'absolute'});

            $(this).parents("table").css("padding-bottom","150px");

        }
        break;
    }

});
```

}

Comment: Can you share this with an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Set `margin-bottom` or set `border-bottom`

Comment: Anything would do, you could even set your body height or margins.. Share code please.

Comment: Use border instead as you can set the color of this.
So have 'border-bottom: 2px solid white' and there will be 2 pixels of white surrounding your table.

Comment: Could you please post your code! This might clarify a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is retaining it's color (blue) because the padding is 'inside' the table. You might want to read more about the [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) to get a better understanding.

You can use jQuery's `wrap` function

```
$("#myTable").wrap("<div></div>");
```

Your table:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go4wyp32/2/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! :) I am unable to vote up because I don't have enough reputation, but you can be sure that when I do have it I will come back and vote it up. Thanks again!